# Make an array with every character on keyboard

Tags: javascript

I want to make an array containing all the letters and numbers on the keyboard (+ !, @, #, $, %, &, etc.) via code, without declaring it. Is there any way to do this in js?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will give characters that are displayable on the screen.

```
let characters = [];

for (let i=32; i<127; i++)
  characters.push( String.fromCharCode(i) );
```

Comment: TypeError: String.characters is not a function

Comment: Updated the code with the right function name.

Comment: i thought it was String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode)

Comment: @AndeCaleb that only works when you're in an event listener for keypress.

Answer (score 1):

I like 1 liners so

```js
const characters = [...Array(95).keys()].map(i => String.fromCharCode(i+32))
```

#### Breakdown for those interested to know whats happening:

- `Array(95).keys()` creates an iterator object with 95 items in it.
- Because its wrapped in brackets `[]`:

  - The spread syntax before it (...) iterates those objects into an array.
- This results in a numbered array from 0 to 94. ie. `[0,1,2,3,...,94]`
- Next you map the data from the array into the `String.fromCharCode` method.

  - Since we want only printable characters (starting from ascii code 32) we add 32 to each number in the source array before piping it into the fromCharCode method.

I've gotten really used to doing this for almost everything because its much faster than writing out a for loop for things. Granted it's slower than a for loop for performance (I think). Usually, I'm not writing code for performance.

Answer (score 0):

There are 95 characters so you can make an array of 95 elements and map the items to the String char code that matches the `index + 32`.

```js
const characters = Array.from(Array(95), (val,i) => String.fromCharCode(i+32))
```